# computed column based on function

Tags: t-sql

I would like to create computed column for profileapplication for below code.

```
Substring(Substring(P.propertyvaluesstring, 
                            Charindex('ProfileApplication', P.propertyvaluesstring), 
                            Charindex('</ProfileApplication',P.propertyvaluesstring) - 
                            Charindex('ProfileApplication',P.propertyvaluesstring)), 
                            Charindex('>', Substring(P.propertyvaluesstring, 
                            Charindex( 'ProfileApplication',P.propertyvaluesstring), 
                            Charindex('</ProfileApplication',P.propertyvaluesstring) - Charindex('ProfileApplication',P.propertyvaluesstring))) 
          + 1, Len(Substring(P.propertyvaluesstring, 
                            Charindex('ProfileApplication', 
                            P.propertyvaluesstring), 
                            Charindex('</ProfileApplication', 
                            P.propertyvaluesstring) - 
                            Charindex('ProfileApplication', 
                            P.propertyvaluesstring))))  AS 
          ProfileApplication,
```

Again, i would like to use ProfileApplication into other query using computed column.  I am not sure but would it be possible?

```
SUBSTRING
        (SUBSTRING
                (P.ProfileApplication,
                    CHARINDEX('RequisitionStartDate', P.ProfileApplication), 
                    CHARINDEX('</RequisitionStartDate',P.ProfileApplication) - 
                    CHARINDEX('RequisitionStartDate',P.ProfileApplication)
                    ), 
                    CHARINDEX('>', SUBSTRING(P.ProfileApplication, 
                    CHARINDEX('RequisitionStartDate', P.ProfileApplication), 
                    CHARINDEX('</RequisitionStartDate',P.ProfileApplication) - 
                    CHARINDEX('RequisitionStartDate', P.ProfileApplication))) + 1, 
                    LEN(SUBSTRING(P.ProfileApplication,
                    CHARINDEX('RequisitionStartDate',P.ProfileApplication),
                    CHARINDEX('</RequisitionStartDate',P.ProfileApplication) - 
                    CHARINDEX('RequisitionStartDate',P.ProfileApplication))))
```

Comment: Can you include your table definition?

Comment: It is impossible to answer the question with what you gave us. In general, we can use string function to create computed column **in a table**. But in what you gave us, there is something like this `P.propertyvaluesstring` which make me think you are trying to refer to column from other tables, which, to the extent of my knowledge, should not be done unless you are creating a view. But that is a different concept.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `propertyvaluesstring` column exists on the same table as the calculated column.

this is what you need to do:

```
ALTER TABLE <your table name here>
ADD ProfileApplication AS SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(propertyvaluesstring, CHARINDEX('ProfileApplication', propertyvaluesstring), CHARINDEX('</ProfileApplication', propertyvaluesstring)-CHARINDEX('ProfileApplication', propertyvaluesstring)), CHARINDEX('>', SUBSTRING(propertyvaluesstring, CHARINDEX('ProfileApplication', propertyvaluesstring), CHARINDEX('</ProfileApplication', propertyvaluesstring)-CHARINDEX('ProfileApplication', propertyvaluesstring)))+1, LEN(SUBSTRING(propertyvaluesstring, CHARINDEX('ProfileApplication', propertyvaluesstring), CHARINDEX('</ProfileApplication', propertyvaluesstring)-CHARINDEX('ProfileApplication', propertyvaluesstring))))
```

Note that calculated columns sometime adversely affect performance so I would be cautious when adding them.